# I am trying to make my first react project using create-react-app but this problem seems to persist

Tags: reactjs, npm, svg, create-react-app

The commands that I entered are

```
npx create-react-app p1
cd p1
npm start
```

and the error that I encountered is

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/logo.svg

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/rudra/.config/svgrrc'
```

I tried using the sudo before the command but it still didn't work. Is there a problem with npm package, should I try reinstalling it?

Comment: It looks like `./src/logo.svg` can't be loaded, perhaps that file has a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file .config in your MAC 
press> shift + cmd + g 
search /Users/rudra/
unhide the file .config pressing cmd + shift + .
rename the file to "config" without dot
create a new file with this name ".config"

and restart your project npm start ;)